# How to call a type from the created index.d.ts file in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following index.d.ts file as a result of importing a Javascript library:

```
import { IPermitCache } from './cache/client';
import { IPermitConfig } from './config';
import { IEnforcer } from './enforcement/enforcer';
import { IDecoratingObject } from './instrument/decorator';
import { IMutationsClient } from './mutations/client';
import { IResourceRegistry } from './resources/registry';
import { IResourceReporter } from './resources/reporter';
import { RecursivePartial } from './utils/types';
export { ISyncedUser, ISyncedRole, IPermitCache } from './cache/client';
export { IUser, IAction, IResource } from './enforcement/interfaces';
export { ITenant, IReadApis, IWriteApis } from './mutations/client';
export { ResourceConfig, ActionConfig } from './resources/interfaces';
export { IUrlContext } from './resources/registry';
export { Context, ContextTransform } from './utils/context';
export interface IPermitClient extends IResourceReporter, IEnforcer, IMutationsClient, IResourceRegistry, IDecoratingObject {
    cache: IPermitCache;
    config: IPermitConfig;
}
/**
 * Permit.io SDK for Node.js
 *
 * You can use this class to enforce permissions in your app.
 *
 * Usage:
 * const permit = new Permit.init({ ... }); // receives a config object of type IPermitConfig
 * const permitted = await permit.check(user, action, resource);
 */
declare class _Permit {
    private _config;
    private _resourceRegistry;
    private _resourceReporter;
    private _enforcer;
    private _cache;
    private _mutationsClient;
    private _appManager;
    constructor(config: RecursivePartial<IPermitConfig>);
}
declare type Permit = _Permit & IPermitClient;
export declare const Permit: new (config: RecursivePartial<IPermitConfig>) => Permit;
```

My question is this:  How, in Typescript, do I actually use the `Permit` constant?

I want to pass in parameters, but if I try

```
const permit = new Permit({ ... });
```

it tells me that `Permit` is not constructible.